# rails foreign key problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-key-relationship

I am a newbie in the Rails framework. I've created tables:

```
DealerGroups                         Dealer 
------------                         ------------
Id:integer(primary key)              Id:integer(primary key)
name:string                          dealer_group_id:integer(foreign key)
```

But when I try to set `Dealer.dealer_group_id = value` (this value exists in the  DealerGroups table) I get an "UninitializedConstant Dealer::DealerGroup" exception.

In models I have :

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dealer_buying_group, :foreign_key => "dealer_buying_group"
end

class DealersGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dealer
end
```

If I delete the `has_many` and `belongs_to` relations, it all works fine.

Why won't it work with the relations?

Comment: 1) Can pls format the code so it's better readable or paste here link to gist or pastebin or slt 2) Can you show us real code which raises the exception? It seems to me the problem is not in your relations, but in getting the value you are assigning to dealer_group_id. Check theese http://bit.ly/k6UuAW , http://bit.ly/lYDuT2 . I am doing there same thing as you are trying and it works

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the "s" (why is your "Dealer" table is not "Dealers"?)
You do not need to manually set a foreign key in Rails, all you need to define the Model_ID field to it as you generate your scaffold/model/controller, then **belongs_to** and **has_many** in the model will do the relation for you

**Database:**

```
DealerGroups                         Dealers 
------------                         ------------
Id:integer(primary key)              Id:integer(primary key)
name:string                          dealergroup_id:integer
```

**Models** :

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dealergroup
end

class DealersGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dealers
end
```

To access dealdergroup's name from dealers, just use

```
controller: 
@dealer = Dealer.find_by_id(myInt)

view:
<%= @dealer.dealergroup.name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have class `DealersGroup` whereas you are looking for `dealer_group_id`.